# Is it possible to have a dynamic route as configure module page?

Tags: 8, routes

I installed the [SEO Checklist](https://www.drupal.org/project/seo_checklist) module and when I go the search in the Extend (admin/modules) page the module Configure page I don't see it, so I go the the module issue an create a new issue [Add link to configure page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2916181) to solve the problem, I thought at the end this will be very easy, the page exists (admin/config/search/seo-checklist) so, is just search the route and add it to the .info.yml file.

But when I start to check the module files I see that the .info.yml file have the configure page defined with the same route that have as url admin/config/search/seo-checklist

```
configure: checklistapi.checklists.seo_checklist
```

So I start to dig a little in the code and I found that this route checklistapi.checklists.seo_checklist is defined dynamically in the [Checklist API](https://www.drupal.org/project/checklistapi) module

```
  $routes["checklistapi.checklists.{$id}"] = new Route($definition['#path'], [
    '_title' => (string) $definition['#title'],
    '_form' => '\Drupal\checklistapi\Form\ChecklistapiChecklistForm',
    'checklist_id' => $id,
    'op' => 'any',
  ], $requirements);
```

I'm missing something here or is not possible to have a dynamic route as configure module page?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67105/discussion-on-question-by-adrian-cid-almaguer-is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-r).

Comment: The routes added in the code are *dynamic* only during discovery. After that they are the same as if they were discovered from a yaml file

Comment: @4k4 In this case I think that this doesn't works, you can try it by your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use any route for the configure link, as long as all route parameters are satisfied (parameters can be specified via `configure_parameters`).

In the case of the above bug, the access check was failing, preventing the link from displaying.

The problem was solved in: [ChecklistapiAccessCheck looks in the wrong place for 'checklist_id' and 'op'](https://www.drupal.org/node/2917760)